# Javascript: I can't find the correct way to phrase a Boolean "IF" to get the result I want

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement

Okay, new to javascript and html and I'm working on a basic form for an in class assignment. It's basically meant to teach us about getting elements from a form and doing something with them.

This is the third part of the assignment and I had no issues with the first two. Now, I can't get this one to work.

```
function lessonLevel_onclick(){
    var code=document.getElementById("txtCode");
    var level=document.getElementById("txtLevel");

    alert(code.value);

    if (code.value == "o" || "O"){
        level.value="Otter";
        alert(code.value);
    }
    else if(code == "n" || "N"){
        level.value="Newt";
        alert(code.value);
    }
    else if(code == "s" || "S"){
        level.value="Sunfish";
        alert(code.value);
    }
    else if(code == "c" || "C"){
        level.value="Crocodile";
        alert(code.value);
    }
    else if(code == "w" || "W"){
        level.value="Whale";
        alert(code.value);
    }
    else{
        level.value="Unknown";
    }
}
```

The alerts serve no purpose other than helping me figure out where it's actually getting to. Basically no matter what input I put in the form the output is Otter... it's as if it doesn't matter what the input is it always makes the first "if" statement true.

What it should do: user enters "o" or "O" and the form outputs swim level "Otter"... "n" or "N" and it's Newt... really, really, really, basic... which is why it's driving me nuts.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong. The alert before the if statement "alert(code.value)" gives me the same as the input. Meaning the input is being taken properly.

So I know the issue is in my boolean. It obviously isn't comparing properly.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

If it helps at all here is the html code I've written.. but I'm fairly sure it isn't the issue:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="scripts/lessonLevel.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <noscript>Please Enable Javascript!</noscript>
        <form>
            <h2>Swimming Lesson Level</h2>
            <p>Enter Lesson Code:
            <input type="text" id="txtCode"></p>
            <p>Lesson Level:
            <input type="text" id="txtLevel" readonly="readonly"></p>
            <input type="button" onclick="lessonLevel_onclick()" value="Determine Level">
            <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And, as I said, ANY input makes the output "Otter" even if I leave it blank...

As a side note: I HAVE tried to turn code.value into a string first, but it doesn't seem to help..

Thank you for your help in advance! If there is anything I can add to clarify, please let me know!

Comment: Try writing this in code: "if x is 1 or y is 2". Now, why do you think "if x is 1 or x is 2" would be any different?

Comment: Another thing to try: `alert(code.value == "o" || "O")` - you should see either `true` or `false`, yes? But you get `O` instead. I wonder why... ;)

Comment: MDN got you covered: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the or operator like you do.
Change

```
if (code.value == "o" || "O"){
```

to

```
if (code.value == "o" || code.value == "O"){
```

Even better: convert the input to lower case before you check:

```
var codeValue = code.value.toLowerCase();
if (codeValue == "o") { ..
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I love/hate learning programming languages for this very reason.. It's always something so simple, and I always end up feeling like a moron! Also good to know about the ".toLowerCase" method! Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You should **not** do this:

```
if (code.value == "o" || "O") // This is BAD
    // This will result in true if either
    // code.value == "o" evaluates to true, or
    // "O" evaluates to true, because strings evaluate to true
```

To actually check whether code.value is "o" or "O", do:

```
if (code.value == "o" || code.value == "O") {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should being doing something more like this:

```
if (code.value.toLowerCase() === "o") {
```

Note, you should almost always use "===" instead of "==" as the former tests whether something's value and data type (number, string, boolean, object, etc.) matches another. "==" performs a type conversion before testing the values. For example:

```
if ("42" == 42) { // true
if ("42" === 42) { // false
```

Comment: *""==" only tests value"* That's too simplistic. It performs type conversion before comparing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing correct if statement.

```
if (code.value == "o" || code.value == "O"){
    //Code to execute
}
```